# Create array names dynamically based on string values in Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var sub=["Maths","Chemistry","Physics"];

for(var i=0;i<sub.length;i++)
 {
   var sub[i]=[];  // this line has error 
 }
```

I want to create and get result as below:

```
Maths[],Chemistry[],Physics[]
```

If it is not possible to get in this way is there any alternate in Javascript to achieve the same

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `Maths[]`? can you show an example of how that would be used?

Comment: Try `sub[i]=[]`, without `var`. You are assigning a property to an object, not declaring a variable.

Comment: just use an object, eg: `var dataStore = { Math: [], Chemistry: [], Physics: [] };`

Comment: this is definitely an example of the XY problem.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378.  What you are demonstrating here isn't standard syntax, and you have given no context as to what it's being used for;  Therefore you are asking about a broken solution to an unknown problem, but the solution you are presenting doesn't make any sense to fix.

Comment: just want to create empty array having names same as string stored in array(sub).

Comment: it will be good if someone could help me out without using object.

Comment: @Saurya: That's totally Okay, Claies just pointed that out, your question is way better than many others who DOES NOT attempt anything. You've shown us X instead of Y, but it's okay, next time, now, you know that you need to post Y :]

Comment: In javascript there are no *variable variables*. You will always be creating variables in some "context". If none given it will implicitly be the global scope (`window` in a browser). Because of that, and because globals are evil, you're better of defining your own context => using an object you have control over.

Comment: right, your question is clear, it just doesn't make any practical sense without context.  why are you trying to pass the variable names as an array of strings? why is using an object unacceptable?

Comment: @Yoshi appreciateyour solution so far i put my best effort and did same as u.

Comment: @Claies using object is not unacceptable but i want another way to this problem. i have found solution using object. But thought if someone could find a way to do without object.

Comment: so essentially, you don't have a practical reason for it, you just want to use a non-standard syntax for no reason at all, except to make your code harder to debug, and confusing to anyone who has to maintain it in the future?  Also, you haven't really described a problem that needs solving; rather, a syntax you want to use.

Comment: There are propably whole book chapters about this topic, so a comment will not suffice, but trust me and the others here: There is almost certainly no good reason to create such variables without an object (or more generally: a defined scope).

Comment: @Kevin B Math[].. is empty array created after executing the code

Comment: So, you would expect to use it with, say, `Math[5] = "foobar"`? or...

Comment: var sub=["Maths","Chemistry","Physics"];
var b={};
for(var i=0;i<sub.length;i++)
{
 b[sub[i]]=[];
}
Output:
{"Maths":[],"Chemistry":[],"Physics":[]}

This is what i got solution for my problem, i guess there is no other way.
Thanks to everyone here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this example helps in addition to the above responses. You can past this code in a browser console and play around with it.

```
var dict = {Math:[], Physics:[], Chemistry:[]};

dict["Math"] = [0, 1, 2];

dict["Chemistry"] = ["organics", "biochemistry"];

dict["Physics"] = ["kinematics", "vectors"];

/*retrieve code by typing following one by one*/

dict["Math"]

dict["Chemistry"]

dict["Physics"]
```

Comment: Exactly this i am going to do. just was thinking if i could do without object by anymeans.

Comment: Probably if you can give a use case, it may help to answer your question better.

Answer (score 3):

```
var sub=["Maths","Chemistry","Physics"];
var result = {};

for(var i=0;i<sub.length;i++)
{
    result[sub[i]] = [];
}
```

I also recommend you read this [article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html) which has a good explanation on how to use objects as associative arrays.

Comment: Missing `]` after `[sub[i]`. -- fixed

Comment: My fault, asking question here for first time.Well cant i do this without putting it in an object.

Comment: You can't solve this without using an object if you plan on accessing the data using the listed keys: "Maths","Chemistry","Physics"